# UWP how to interaction with , which canvas.zindex value is lower among two canvas one over another?

Tags: c#, uwp

I have a Parent Canvas.That Parent Canvas has two child Canvas One over another with same height and width.Fisrt child Canvas has zindex=0,and second child Canvas has zindex=1.The second Child Canvas has many child Image(UIElement).i want,my second canvas must have higher zindex.I have PointerPressed event for first canvas , second canvas and on each Image also.I want,if I Click on image it fire PointerPressed event of the Image and if I click on canvas where the image is not present ,it must fire first canvas pointerPressed event whose zindex is 0.I don't know how to achieve this??

My XAML Code:

```
<Canvas x:Name="MyCanvas">
    <Canvas x:Name="FirstCanvas" Canvas.ZIndex="0" PointerPressed="FirstCanvas_PointerPressed" Width="1500" Height="700">
        <!--Child Elements-->
    </Canvas>
    <Canvas x:Name="SecondCanvas" Canvas.ZIndex="1" PointerPressed="SecondCanvas_PointerPressed" Width="1500" Height="700">
        <Image x:Name="FistImage" Source="image1.jpg" Width="100" Height="100" PointerPressed="FistImage_PointerPressed" Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="0"></Image>
        <Image x:Name="SecondImageImage" Source="image2.jpg" Width="100" Height="100" PointerPressed="SecondImageImage_PointerPressed" Canvas.Left="200" Canvas.Top="200"></Image>
    </Canvas>
</Canvas>
```

My C# Code:

```
    private void FirstCanvas_PointerPressed(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void SecondCanvas_PointerPressed(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void FistImage_PointerPressed(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void SecondImageImage_PointerPressed(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

Comment: Hello, Are your two Canvas completely overlapping or separated? Can you provide some code to explain your intentions?

Comment: my two canvas were overlapped!

Comment: Sorry I am not very clear about the function you want to achieve. Do you mean that when you click on the picture in the top Canvas, only the `PointerPressed` event of the picture will be triggered, and will not continue to trigger the `PointerPressed` event of TopCanvas?

Comment: i had provide some code..please checkit out

Comment: no,if i click on top canvas where the image is not present ,i want to fire below canvas pointerpressed event i.e.,FirstCanvas whose zindex is 0.

Comment: @RichardZhang-MSFT ,Did you understand what I'm trying to asked??

Comment: @RichardZhang-MSFT,   I Have one more Doubt !! when I click on image, Is it possible to call pointerpressed event of firstcanvas instead of image pointerpressedevent??

Comment: No. First, the `PointerPressed` event occurs on the Image, and secondly, `FirstCanvas` is not the parent element of the Image, and the event will not bubble through the `FirstCanvas`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand what you mean, here are some explanations:

In the code you provided, the background color of Canvas is transparent. For this transparent container control, the pointer can penetrate. So it will not trigger `PointerPressed` event.

If you want to make it handle the pointer event, set the same background color as the page like:

```xml
<Canvas x:Name="FirstCanvas" Canvas.ZIndex="0" 
        PointerPressed="FirstCanvas_PointerPressed" Width="1500" Height="700"
        Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <!--Child Elements-->
</Canvas>
```

If there is an element that needs to be displayed under your Canvas, you can give the background color a very low opacity:

```xml
<Canvas x:Name="MyCanvas">
    <Canvas.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="LowOpacityBackground" Color="White" Opacity="0.01"/>
    </Canvas.Resources>
    <Canvas ...
            Background="{ThemeResource LowOpacityBackground}">
        <!--Child Elements-->
    </Canvas>
</Canvas>
```

In short, the background color cannot be completely transparent.

Thanks.

Comment: yeah its working. How can i add it dynamically(c#) to firstcanvas .

Comment: when I dynamically add it ,it won't work ..What i had did is?
SolidColorBrush solidColorBrush = new SolidColorBrush();
solidColorBrush.Opacity = 0.01;
solidColorBrush.Color = Colors.White;
FirstCanvas.Background = solidColorBrush;
Is it Correct???

Comment: I tested this code, it can normally assign values to `Canvas.Background`. Where did you call this assignment statement?

Comment: Same Case .But instead of Multiple Image Control, I have CanvasControl .In that CanvasControl , I am going to Draw Mutiple Images at different locations.For this layout ,how to achieve the above solution??